# Eclipse plugin Incubator's "Web Templates (Advanced)" plugin (with secured Redmine): Failed to parse RSS feed / invalid xml

Tags: eclipse, redmine, mylyn, redmine-api

Trying to connect some restricted Redmine instance to our Eclipse Mylyn environment it worked in the beginning, but the re-imports did not with some error "Failed to parse RSS feed".

I stumbled across this [#246440 Eclipse Mylyn ticket](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=246440) where some workaround was to recreate the `Task Repository` including the `Task List Queries` by hand.
But this is not a nice solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I played around a bit more and found the following that solved our import issues:

1. most likely for your needs: remove the `key` value (or other security-relevant data) from the exported `<task list query>.xml.zip / tasklist.xml` since the queries contain some user-dependent authentication API (e.g. if shared with other users)

   - it should anyways be configured on your related `Task Repository` for all dependent queries and will be re-imported automatically on later import
2. make sure that (e.g. through some used formatter, `CTRL + F` or manual formatting) there are **no whitespaces in text-value XML nodes**, because thus the queries may stop working after import:

   - e.g.

     ```
     <Attribute Key="Regexp">^({Id}\d+);({Type}[^;]*);...$
     </Attribute>
     ```

     should be:

     ```
     <Attribute Key="Regexp">^({Id}\d+);({Type}[^;]*);...$</Attribute>
     ```
3. go on **`Task List -> <your imported query> -> right click -> Properties -> Finish`** so some internal magic "fixes" your query

Another debugging hint: you can always check the retrieved files (and `Query Pattern` regexp using the `Preview` button) using the `<your query -> Properties -> Advanced Configuration -> Open` button, which should put the unparsed query result in e.g. `c:\Users\<loginname>\AppData\Local\Temp\mylyn-web-connector4155864524987884464.html`.

---

By the way: (If you are at the above point it may likely be useful for you or your team ...) Using the web connector I found the integration via the API key in combination with the `.../issues.csv...` format much more useful and configurable than the `.../issues.xml...` variant.
We used something like this for parsing the CSV (and generated the params, their order etc. via normal filter dialogs): `^({Id}\d+);({Type}[^;]*);({Status}[^;]*);"?({Owner}[^";]*)"?;({Description}[^;]*)$`.
Advantages are: easier regexp, concatenatable data for `Description` via column-ordering and fetching of all data without paging (=> we could skip `page`, `per_page`, `limit`, `offset`).